# How many ways can 12 different pennies be distributed to four people without each person getting exactly 3?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

**Question:** How many ways can $\mathbf{12}$ different pennies be distributed to four people without each person getting exactly $\mathbf{3}$?

**My thoughts:** I'm really not too sure how to approach this question. Any recommendations for a less visual way of solving this problem - a more systematic approach.

Comment: Could you solve it without the restriction, i.e., if the problem were simply to give the number of ways to distribute $12$ different pennies to $4$ people?

Comment: Yes, does it relate to solving it with the restriction? I was considering using the complement, but I wasn't sure if this was possible - and if it is, how.

Comment: Get the total number of distributions, and then subtract the number that give $3$ coins to each person. That’s just a matter of choosing $3$ coins for the first person, $3$ of the remaining coins for the second person, and so on.

Comment: I'm getting a small error in my answer. To solve the problem without the restriction is: **({12}{3}) = 495**. I then did as you said and subtracted **495 - ({12}{3}) - ({9}{3}) - ({6}{3}) - 1 = 170**. However, the answer should be **165**. Any idea what I'm missing as I'm having a hard time spotting out my mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $(\{12\}\{3\})$?

Comment: \binom{12}3=220 **12 elements choose 3**

Comment: But $\binom{12}3=220$, not $495$.

Comment: Whoops I apologize for that mishap there that caused confusion. I meant 12 choose 4 there. Give me a sec. I'm reading the wrong problem. ~Long day. I'll respond with a more suitable response shorty.

Comment: Okay; it looks to me as if you’re getting off on the wrong foot altogether. $\binom{12}4$ is just the number of ways to pick out $4$ of the $12$ coins. Distributing $12$ distinct coins to $4$ people entails making a $4$-way choice of recipient for each coin, so it can be done in $4^{12}$ ways, if you don’t care how many coins anyone gets. This includes all of the distributions in which each person gets $3$ coins, all of the distributions in which one person gets all $12$ coins, etc.

Comment: I apologize @BrianM.Scott . I feel like I've wasted your time since I was referencing a  question in my notes where the pennies were identical, which is not what I asked here. I see where my error resides and thank you kindly for your help. I ended up with 4^12 - ( ({12}{3}) * ({9}{3}) * ({6}{3}) * 1) = 16,407,616. Side note: how are you formatting your MathJax text; mine isn't working.

Comment: That’s okay, and yes, that’s the answer that I get as well. For MathJax, take a look at [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and see if you still have questions. As an example, $\binom{12}4$ is `$\binom{12}{4}$`.

Comment: Didn't work before but test just in case: $\binom{12}{4}$
**Test(s)**
$\binom{12}{4}$
$\sqrt{x^3}$
This '$' character solves it. I'll read as to why it does. Thanks a lot Brian!

Comment: You’re welcome! The dollar signs tell the system to interpret what’s between them as MathJax.

Comment: This exercise will now be fruitful if Le Sunstrike posts this answer himself. I will definitely upvote it

Comment: @Shailesh Went ahead and posted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to tackle this problem can be viewed as a three step process.
We first must distribute $\mathbf{12}$ *different* pennies to $\mathbf{4}$ different people, which gives us an overall possible combinations of: 
$$\mathbf{4^{12} = 16,777,216}$$
With this in mind, we use the formula for combinations $\binom{n}{k}$ and distribute $\mathbf{3}$ coins to each person:
$$ \mathbf{\binom{12}{3} \ast \ \binom{9}{3} \ast \binom{6}{3} \ast \binom{3}{3} = 369, 600}$$
Now we subtract this value - the amount of possibilities that distribute 3 pennies to each person - from the total of possible combinations to find our solution: $$\mathbf{16,777,216 - 369,600 = 16,407,616}$$ Thus, there are $\mathbf{16,407,616}$ possibilities for giving 12 distinct pennies to **four** people.

Comment: Very nice. +1.  Something wrong with the formatting or is it my computer.

Comment: @Shailesh I am not seeing anything wrong with format. Where are you seeing weird stuff, so that I can inspect it.

Comment: It appears OK now.  It must have been my computer